# Code for uploading photos to photobucket in android?

Tags: android

I am searching for android code to upload photographs to photobucket, still found nothing. Please help me with some sample codes.

Comment: searching for ready made code..Wow!! You are great.

Answer (score 2):

- Here [is the Photobucket jar](https://bitbucket.org/photobucket/api-java/src/02f9d15b7bae/build.xml)
- [Here](https://bitbucket.org/photobucket/api-java/overview/) is some [sample code](https://bitbucket.org/photobucket/api-java/get/666525a00573.zip)